# CollectionView indexPath.row is not correct? (Inside TableViewCell)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that I want the indexPath.row to. However, whenever I try to print/display the indexPath.row number, it's off. It's a horizontal collection view, so when I try to page right, it goes from: 0, 2, 3, 4, 5 and going backwards it jumps to 5,3,2,1,1,1. It's also varies each time.

Currently the collectionView is inside a tableViewCell. The data is getting loaded off of Firebase database.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCollectionViewCell
        
        
        pageController.currentPage = indexPath.row
        pageController.numberOfPages = userList.count
        
        
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting Prefetching enabled to false in storyboard worked.